# How to pass variables received in GET string through a php header redirect?

Tags: php, variables, header, get

I'm receiving values in a GET string from Aweber upon user's submission of a form. I take the variables they send and submit them to a SMS gateway to notify a 3rd party of the submission by text message.

Here's my problem. I need to redirect the page that performs the outgoing SMS commands in a php header to another page that finally displays the GET variables sent from Aweber.

I can retrieve the variables and their values in the first page. How do I pass them to the second page?

Here is the code I'm using on the first page (sms.php) to collect the variables sent by Aweber:

```
   $fname   = $_GET['name'];
   $femail  = $_GET['email'];
   $fphone  = $_GET['telephone'];
   ....etc

   header('Location: confirmed.php');
   exit;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['fname']   = $_GET['name'];
$_SESSION['femail']  = $_GET['email'];
$_SESSION['fphone']  = $_GET['telephone'];
....etc

header('Location: confirmed.php');
```

and get it on the next page like:

```
session_start();
$fname   = $_SESSION['fname'];
$femail  = $_SESSION['femail'];
$fphone  = $_SESSION['fphone'];
```

....etc

Comment: Works like a charm! Though @Yan basically suggested the same, I appreciate your detailed explanation (which helped this novice ;)

Comment: Or just `$_SESSION['get'] = $_GET;`

Answer (score 24):

First convert the `$_GET` HTTP variable into a query string using

```
$query = http_build_query($_GET);
```

Then append the query string variable to your redirect header

```
header('location: domain.com'."?".$query);
```

Done.

Comment: if you have a `?value=4%2e20` it will be change to `?value=4.20` . And later `$_POST['amount_value'] == 4.20` it will return false .

Comment: How about this:  `$query = urlencode(http_build_query($_GET));`

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to store them in a session, you can easily pass them with your location header:

```
$fname   = $_GET['name'];
$femail  = $_GET['email'];
$fphone  = $_GET['telephone'];
//now a header with these var's:
header("Location: confirmed.php?name=".$fname."&email=".$femail."&telephone=".$fphone);
```

In confirmed.php you can get these variables with $_GET method.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried this solution before posting the question here and all I got was `.$fname` on the confirmed.php page when echoing it, instead of the actual value in the GET string

Comment: Can you post your code of the php with the header("location...) in it and confirmed.php where you were trying to echo that?

Comment: I was using the same `$fname=$_GET['name'];` in both pages since the parameters in both strings were the same, ie `name=value`

Comment: When this page is called, you are immediately redirected to http://www.yourdomain.com/confirmed.php and this is the URL you see in your browser. Do you see the variables in the URL?

Comment: Yes, but they come up as `confirmed.php?name=".$fname"&email=".$femail"` etc, instead of the actual values in place of `".$fname"` and `".$femail"`.

Comment: Did you notice the difference between < ".$fname" > and < ".$fname." >

I suspect you forgot the point behind the variable name in the header().

Comment: Weird:
<?php
$name = 'foo';
header("Location: test2.php?name=".$name."");
?>

works perfectly for my, just tested it on local webserver :S

Comment: if you have a `?value=4%2e20` it will be change to `?value=4.20` . And later `$_POST['amount_value'] == 4.20` it will return false .

Answer (score 3):

Please for anyone reading this in future, use sessions for this kind of variable value transfer because if you rely mostly on adding variable to header then if the user in still on that form and carries out an action that changes the value of the header then your own variable value changes since it depends on the header......simply put, USE SESSIONS.

Answer (score 2):

Store them in the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php):

```
 $_SESSION['fname'] = $_GET['name'];
```

Use `session_start` at the beginning of each file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It worked perfectly for me.

```
if ($_GET)
{
    $query = str_replace("%3D", "=", str_replace("%26", "&", strval(urlencode(http_build_query($_GET)))));

    header('location: https://www.example.com'.'?'.$query);
}
else
{
    header('location: https://www.example.com');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is put all your POST variables to a session like this:

**On page1.php put:**

```
//Start the session
session_start();
//Dump your POST variables
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
```

**And on page2.php put: (*If on page1.php we use a normal POST form submit with form `action="page2.php`"*)**

```
//Start the session
session_start();
//Access your POST variables
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
//Unset the useless session variable
unset($_SESSION['post-data']);
```

**Or on page2.php put: (*If on page1.php we use a self submit with form `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>` and then use a `header("Location: page2.php");` to move to the page2.php and pass our POST variables via a session*)**

```
//Start the session
session_start();
//Access your POST variables
$_POST = $_SESSION['post-data'];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
unset($_SESSION['post-data']);
```

I literally spent hours figuring that out because all the forums put it wrong or incomplete.

Now it's as easy as just calling the variables you passed from the page1.php like this for example: `<b>Points: </b><?php echo $points; ?>` and that's it!!

When situating the `header('Location: page2.php');` in a `if` condition, etc. make sure that it will be in the first PHP script of the page and above any HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

This works use this sentex

header('location:member_dashboard.php?id='.$id);