# Storing all POST data in SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have more values (over 20) from $_POST like this...

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
```

NOTE : I have prevented there values from SQL injection.

My question is can I know is there a way to store all these POST values in SESSION at once? 
Instead of this method..

`$_SESSION['name'] = $name;` etc

any answers will be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
```

That will create an array of the post values in a single session variable. The values would be accessible as

```
$_SESSION['post-data']['name']
$_SESSION['post-data']['username']
...
```

Comment: can you explain it little with my above POST variables

Comment: Then don't I need to add $_POST['name'] etc respectively?

Comment: OK.. but one thing, I have assign POST values to variables.. $name = $_POST['name']; etc.. Then what happen?

Comment: What happens if there are multiple `$_POST`'s on the pages? How can i set a specific `$_POST` ?

Answer (score 9):

You can add one array to another.
`$_POST` and `$_SESSION` are just arrays.
Note that the keys in the second array take priority in case of duplicates.

```
$_SESSION += $_POST;
```

However, I don't see this ending well, since the client side can inject anything he wants to the session, E.G. hijacking your users session id.

Comment: please explain with an example... Thank you

Comment: $_SESSION += $_POST; that is the example.

Comment: Simple and elegant.  +1

Comment: I don't know whether this changed but values in the first array take priority with duplicate keys. See https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 3):

If you looking for session variables that are set using the same key as the posted array, you could use this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

This will make your $_POST array into variables based on the array key and also set the session at the same time. You could then access your `name` post by using either `$_SESSION['name']` or `$name`.

This means you will not need to use: `$name = $_POST['name'];` anymore. As the above code will set the name variable for you and also set the session variable.

Comment: can you show me an example for this line : If you looking for session variables that are set using the same key as the posted array

Comment: This will convert your post array into variables and session variables in one go. Meaning if you post `name=Bob` it will convert it to `$name = 'Bob';` and also `$_SESSION['name'] = 'Bob';`.

Comment: Why worry about the form having a field name that matches and effectively overwrites the session var without you realizing it? Pushing the entire post array into a single session var just makes a multidimensional out of $_POST with no chance of data loss.

Comment: what does "${$key} = $value;" do?

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation of passing variables either with form post or header location redirection inside php check out my answer in this thread: [How to pass variables received in GET string through a php header redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803343/how-to-pass-variables-received-in-get-string-through-a-php-header-redirect/)