# Passing emails in PHP header redirect - strips "@"?

Tags: php, variables, header, get

I'm receiving the GET variables from my autoresponder (getResponse) when someone subscribes to my list, and I need to pass these on to a survey provider in another GET request. I use the PHP "header()" function but the "@" character gets stripped from the email.

Here's my PHP code:

```
// retrieve email from GET
$email = $_GET['email'];

// pass on email
header("Location: http://surveyprovider.com/surveyID/start?email=$email");
```

Let's assume I'm getting *"?email=someguy@someserver.com"* when getResponse calls my PHP script. When my script runs, the resulting HTTP call looks like this:

```
http://surveyprovider.com/surveyID/start?email=someguysomeserver.com
```

**Notice how the "@" is missing** in the email address?

How do I fix this problem?

I can't use session variables (like suggested in this question: [How to pass variables received in GET string through a php header redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803343/how-to-pass-variables-received-in-get-string-through-a-php-header-redirect)) because the survey provider doesn't let me retrieve session variables (no custom PHP scripting).

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode that URL properly.  You're currently not sending a valid URL.

```
header('Location: http://surveyprovider.com/surveyID/start?email=' . urlencode($email));
```

The `@` becomes `%40`:

```
http://surveyprovider.com/surveyID/start?email=test%40example.com
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Thank you Brad. Will the receiving server interpret that correctly? In other words, when the %40 shows up on the URI, will they have to "de-encode" it to store a proper email address? (I doubt the encoded character will usable as an email address)...

Comment: Also, you mention that my URL isn't valid... then how is it that the email address actually shows up with an @ in the GET string (I don't do any decoding when I retrieve it)?  Just wondering...

Comment: @MichaelM, Yes, of course the server can interpret that. It's the standard. You don't have to do any decoding, PHP does it for you, parsing the whole querystring and populates `$_GET` accordingly. The reason it works when you type it into your browser is that your browser is nice to you and fixes it for you before sending to the server. If the browser wasn't nice to you, it's likely that the server would be.If the it wasn't, it's likely that PHP would be. In any case, it isn't correct. Reserved characters must be encoded. See also:  http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: Incidentally, I'm going to use this code to automatically encode the email for me:         $email = (isset($_GET['email']) ? filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED) : '');

Comment: @MichaelM, Why not just use `urlencode()`?  There is no reason to use `filter_var()` in this case.