# send the variable to another page in php

Tags: php

I have two pages in php ,one of them is exam page(exam.php) and another is result page(result.php), the result is calculated in exam page and must be sent to result page to display.(I don't have a form)
to send the result, Inside exam.php ,I write, header("location:result.php?result");
and to get the result inside result.php ,I write, $newresult=$_GET['result'];
but I receive error,and result didn't sent to the result page.
would you please guide me?

Comment: Please mark the correct answer ya for which solutions that solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use session

**exam.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['result'] = $result;

?>
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['result'];

?>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants it to be done through a URL.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803343/how-to-pass-variables-received-in-get-string-through-a-php-header-redirect

Comment: @Script47 if he/she wants to use GET, the user can modify the result :)

Comment: Wrong, *result.php* doesn't have `session_start` so it will throw an error.

Comment: thank u so much @MuthalFury, I get result with your answer.

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers. :)

Comment: @script47 ,@ MuthaFury,Actually I put session_start() inside result page ,and i didn't get any error.its not correct?

Comment: @Nilla I don't get what you meant. You can there is error?

Comment: @script47 said, inside result.php we couldn't put session_start, but I add it and I didn't get any error.is it correct?

Comment: yes, it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using a URL to pass parameters can be done like so.

**HTML**

```
<a href='yourPage.php?name=Script47'>Send Variable</a>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name') && !empty(trim($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']), ENT_QUOTES);
}
?>
```

**Explanation**

The `HTML` is fairly simple, we create a link which holds a parameter specified after the page extension (`?name=[...]`).

The `PHP` first checks if the `name` parameter which was passed `isset` to prevent an *undefined index error*, and we check if it isn't `empty`. The `trim` function removes white spaces so an string with a space isn't outputted (`" "`). When we know that the string has a value in it we sanitize it (never trust user input) and then we output it.

**Reading Material**

[`htmlspecialchars();`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwj-jbmGnN_IAhWBNhoKHT-DBXM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.htmlspecialchars.php&usg=AFQjCNHmoCDGZOBx6ZvY6UkakTVFWNf0RA&bvm=bv.105841590,d.d24)

[`trim();`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjABahUKEwi0tpOJnN_IAhXMWhoKHWM2Btw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.trim.php&usg=AFQjCNGQYqVcBTE3SA_feldPz3zQP3GfCw&bvm=bv.105841590,d.d24)

[`empty();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

[`isset();`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiItaOHnN_IAhUCzxoKHXSwCII&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.isset.php&usg=AFQjCNEilnOC2VNydDdQDAXjnJjWAYf6Mg)

Comment: @Nilla glad I could help.