# How to access variable value from another php script

Tags: php, query-string

I have read so many pages and am stuck on this for the past three hours now because it just won't work.

I keep getting Notice: Undefined index: firstname

here is the bulk of the segment that isn't working:

```
$errMsg = "";

function sanitise($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST["firstname"]))
{
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $firstname = sanitise($firstname);

    if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z \-]+$/",$firstname))
    {
        $errMsg .= "First name must contain only letters or hyphens.<br/>";
    }

    if (strlen($firstname) > 40)
    {
        $errMsg .= "First name cannot be over 40 characters long.<br/>";
    }
} else {
    $errMsg .= "First name cannot be empty.<br/>";
    $firstname = "";
}


    if ($errMsg != "")
    {
    header("Location: fix_order.php?firstname=$firstname");
    }
```

this is the code on fix_order.php where I want to access the variables.

```
$firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
echo "<p>firstname is $firstname .</p>";
```

I have tested the $firstname on the first page and it echo's the values just fine.

Comment: You can also use sessions to store the variables across pages. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803399/5914775) for more information.

Comment: Use `header("Location: fix_order.php?firstname=".$firstname);`

Comment: Where is `$firstname` defined in the script that writes the header?

Comment: This script is working, maybe you have some other errors

Comment: I suspect there's something you're not showing us - technically what you've got there *should* work.

Comment: @CD001 yes, something is missing here

Comment: sorry the assignment requirements asks to use Query string and not session storage.

Comment: How would I find these errors? do you seriously want me to put 350 lines of code on this? what should I look for ?

Comment: Print `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` and show us the result

Comment: @Noob post the line that gives you the error

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: firstname in /home/students/accounts/s6883826/cos10011/www/htdocs/assign3/fix_order.php on line 24

Comment: print $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];  
 
OUTPUT= array

Comment: Write `print_r($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);` I was hoping that by saying print you will use `print_r`

Comment: @RaviHirani sorry mate I am still learning... I did what you typed, and still the output is "array"

Comment: @Noob: Please refer this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to

```
$firstname = $_GET["errMsg"];
echo "<p>firstname is $firstname .</p>";
```

You can't access `$firstname` as this is the value not the key. `errMsg` is the key you should use.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: errMsg in /home/students/accounts/s6883826/cos10011/www/htdocs/assign3/fix_order.php on line 24

Comment: sorry mate, i had it as errMsg before to test something. I changed the key back to firstname and I still run into the same errors.

Notice: Undefined index: firstname in /home/students/accounts/s6883826/cos10011/www/htdocs/assign3/fix_order.php on line 24

Comment: the code you pasted is not complete right?, do you have any other  `header` location?

Comment: i pasted it there... but can you see it?

Comment: i added it. it isn't complete yet. matter of fact most of it will be scrapped as I am recreating a new page there. below the 3rd php script, will be changed...

Comment: I think you are calling `$_GET['firstaname']` in either `main.inc` or `menu.inc` as I have commented them out and it works, no errors.

Comment: I just posted the answer from one of the comments from the actual question. Thank you anyway for your time! I really appreciate it! especially after 4 hours of pulling my hair out... was a simple full stop...

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, it should work.

To get rid of the notice, you need to define variable by using isset()

```
$firstname = isset($_GET['firstname']) ? $_GET['firstname'] : '';
```

OR

```
if(isset($_GET['firstname'])) {
    $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
} else {
    $firstname = '';
}
```