# JS - Redirect and return to home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have an issue, I want to create a script in Page1 and after X seconds redirect to Page2, and inside Page2 return to Page1, and make it is not difficult, and here is my issue, after return from Page 2, I want to redirect to Page3, and return to Page1, and when I reurn from Page3 I want to redirect to Page4, every redirect with X seconds.
I know I can redirect with meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="X; 
URL=Page2.com">
```

and the same tag for Page2 to return to Page1, but I need to do is something like this in Page1

```
<!-- First Redirect -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="x; URL=Page2.com">
<!-- Second Redirect -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="x+x; URL=Page3.com">
<!-- Third Redirect -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="x+x+x; URL=Page4.com">
<!-- Fouth Redirect -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="x+x+x+x; URL=Page5.com">
```

There is someway to that in script? because it didn't work, always redirect me to Page1.com.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: i think better you explain why do you want to do with these instead how to doing these

Comment: [If you're willing to learn a bit of php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803343/how-to-pass-variables-received-in-get-string-through-a-php-header-redirect)

Comment: @GalAbra where he mentioned php?

Comment: I think in two ways of doing that (i'm not so much experienced, maybe someone can think in another ideas), you can pass by URL parameter the value of last page and then in page1 you verify to where is the next redirect and then do this with JS. Or you can store a variable in the local/session storage and again verify it to set the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this way:

```
<script>
let urls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('urls') || '[-1]')
let urlList = ['page2.com', 'page3.com', 'page4.com']

if(urls[0] == -1) { // fresh start
localStorage.setItem('urls', JSON.stringify(urlList))
startRedirection('page1.com') 
} else if(urls.length == 0) { // all redirects done
console.log("Exhausted")
localStorage.removeItem('urls') // removes the key "urls" for a fresh start
location.reload();
} else {
const url = urls.shift() // get the first url in "urls" array and remove it 
from the array
localStorage.setItem('urls', JSON.stringify(urls)) // update the state
startRedirection(url) // redirect
}

function startRedirection(url) {
setTimeout(() => location.href = url, 2000)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a stateful solution. Here's a possible solution:

```
// PAGEX content where X = 2, 3, 4, 5...
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="X; URL=page1.com">
```

and

```
// PAGE1 content:

<script>
let urls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('urls') || '[-1]')
let urlList = ['page2.com', 'page3.com', 'page4.com']

if(urls[0] == -1) { // fresh start
  localStorage.setItem('urls', JSON.stringify(urlList))
  startRedirection(urlList[0])
} else if(urls.length == 0) { // all redirects done
  console.log("Exhausted")
  localStorage.removeItem('urls') // removes the key "urls" for a fresh start
} else {
  const url = urls.shift() // get the first url in "urls" array and remove it from the array
  localStorage.setItem('urls', JSON.stringify(urls)) // update the state
  startRedirection(url) // redirect
}

function startRedirection(url) {
  setTimeout(() => location.href = url, 2000)
}

</script>
```

Comment: Excellent!!!! thanks dude!!! Just in 
function startRedirection(url) {
  setTimeout(() => location.href = url, 2000)
}
I modify
function startRedirection(url) {
  setTimeout(function(){ location.href = url;}, 2000)
}
And it works!, this is the last thing... Do you know how to make it infinite?thanks!

Comment: Infinite? Can you explain the flow? @Dibu Escobedo

Comment: something like this,
page1=> page2=>page1
page1=>page3=>page1
page1=>page4=>page1
page1=> page2=>page1
page1=>page3=>page1
page1=>page4=>page1
page1=> page2=>page1
page1=>page3=>page1
page1=>page4=>page1
page1=> page2=>page1
page1=>page3=>page1
page1=>page4=>page1 and so on, and so on
I try to make something like this
bool var valida=true;
do{
script
}
while(valida == true){

}

Comment: summaring never ends to make the same thing

Answer (score 0):

page1.html : OnLoad check the url parameter for next page

```
function onLoad(){
   var url_string = window.location.href;
   var url = new URL(url_string);

   //Set pageName and time from url or some default value.
   var pageName = url.searchParams.get("pageName") !== null ? 
url.searchParams.get("pageName") : 'page2.html';
   var time = url.searchParams.get("time") !== null ? url.searchParams.get("time") : 1000;

   setTimeout(function(){
     window.location = pageName;
   }, parseInt(time));
}
```

page2.html : Pass next redirect page as parameter

```
function onLoad(){
    window.location = 'page1.html?pageName=page3.html&time=2000'
}
```