# PHP header doesn't include variables no matter what

Tags: php

I'm trying to include some GET parameters in a header redirect URL but they won't pass to the second page no matter what.

Code:

```
    if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
        $ref = $_GET['ref'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['placem'])) {
        $ad = $_GET['placem'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['dse'])) {
        $adset = $_GET['dse'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['cmp'])) {
        $campaign = $_GET['cmp'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['aud'])) {
        $audience = $_GET['aud'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['gen'])) {
        $gender = $_GET['gen'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['sub1'])) {
        $subid1 = $_GET['sub1'];
    }

    if (isset($_GET['fb_login'])) {
        header('Location: /functions/fb_login.php?ref='.urlencode($ref).'&placem='.urlencode($ad).'&dse='.urlencode($adset).'&cmp='
            .urlencode($campaign).'&aud='.urlencode($audience).'&gen='.urlencode($gender).'&sub1='.urlencode($subid1) );
    }

    echo 'Location: /functions/fb_login.php?ref='.urlencode($ref).'&placem='.urlencode($ad).'&dse='.urlencode($adset).'&cmp='
        .urlencode($campaign).'&aud='.urlencode($audience).'&gen='.urlencode($gender).'&sub1='.urlencode($subid1); 

    //echo result : Location: /functions/fb_login.php?ref=test&placem=test&dse=test-Big&cmp=campaign_01&aud=bb.aa.33&gen=m&sub1=111111111111111

    // address bar result: /functions/fb_login.php?ref=&placem=&dse=&cmp=&aud=&gen=&sub1=
```

Can anyone please point me to what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ok the addres bar look funky, but have you tried accessing $_GET, do the values exist or no?

Comment: Yeah well, I convert them into a JSON on `fb_login.php` and the result is: `{ "ref": "", "placem": "", "dse": "", "cmp": "", "aud": "", "gen": "", "sub1": "" }`

Comment: dont know why empty, http_build_query might work, also one of these might work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803343/how-to-pass-variables-received-in-get-string-through-a-php-header-redirect

Comment: @Andrew the trick with `$_SESSION` worked! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
$var = '';
if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
    $ref = $_GET['ref'];
    $var .= "ref='.urlencode($ref).'&";
}
if (isset($_GET['placem'])) {
    $ad = $_GET['placem'];
    $var .= "placem='.urlencode($ad).'&";
}
if (isset($_GET['dse'])) {
    $adset = $_GET['dse'];
    $var .= "dse='.urlencode($adset).'&";
}
if (isset($_GET['cmp'])) {
    $campaign = $_GET['cmp'];
    $var .= "cmp='.urlencode($campaign).'&";
}
if (isset($_GET['aud'])) {
    $audience = $_GET['aud'];
    $var .= "aud='.urlencode($audience).'&";
}
if (isset($_GET['gen'])) {
    $gender = $_GET['gen'];
    $var .= "gen='.urlencode($gender).'&";
}
if (isset($_GET['sub1'])) {
    $subid1 = $_GET['sub1'];
    $var .= "sub1='.urlencode($subid1).'";
}

if (isset($_GET['fb_login'])) {
    header('Location: /functions/fb_login.php?'.$var );
}
```